# Can't see hard drives in disk management

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have several external WD hard drives, and I removed their cases and converted them to internal hard drives.

I see them in the BIOS, but when I go to Windows, I can't see them at all.
I checked Disk Management, they are not visible there either.

I have data on those disks, and don't want to format at all. What are my options?

[image]

[image]

After shutting down and restarting again, I can see them in the disk management.  So, one of them is now online, but the other one is not initialized and not online. I have data on it, and I can't format it.

What should i do with this one?

Comment: Are the drives visible under Disk drives in Device Manager? Also, try clicking **Rescan Disks** from the Action menu of Disk Management.

Comment: Post screenshot of your view from the device manager and disk management

Comment: @Bonnard Please supply us the information we requested.

Comment: @FastEthernet i added the new screenshot, and they are visible, but one of them is offline

Comment: @Ramhound please see the post, i updated the question

Comment: @TomEus i provided the screenshot of the disk management

Comment: @Bonnard - The drive is not intialized because the external drive was formatted with one sector size but was natively another sector size.  Now since you are talking directly to the drive, you have a sector size conflict, the simplest solution is to put it back into the enclsure and move the data off the drive and format it again when its connected natively.  *ALL* other solutions require deeper knowlege on how to analyze your current situtation and is not for situation where you don't have a backup of the data.  *You have been warned*